# optparse: Support additional prefixes on integer arguments?

Tags: python, optparse

optparse supports the '0b', '0' and '0x' prefixes on integer arguments to signify binary, octal and hexadecimal respectively. I need to support some additional prefixes, including '%' for binary and '$' for hex.

One way to do this would be to patch [optparse._parse_num](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/optparse.py#l400), as follows:

```
oldParseNum = optparse._parse_num
def newParseNum(val, type):
    val = re.sub('^%', '0b', val)
    val = re.sub('^\$', '0x', val)
    return oldParseNum(val, type)
optparse._parse_num = newParseNum
```

Although this does work, it seems quite fragile. Is there a better approach?

Comment: Do you need to use optparse? argparse is newer, and has an extensible type system: https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#type

Comment: @anon: The code already uses optparse, and I would rather leave it mostly unchanged if possible. However, it appears that optparse also has a documented method to [add new types](https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html#adding-new-types).

Answer (score 0):

You could define your own option-handler/-callback:

```
parser.add_option("-c", action="callback", callback=my_callback)
```

to handle special cases or extend the syntax.

Take a look into the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html#optparse-option-callbacks) to determine if this would be sufficient for you and better then (monkey-)patching.